# Trouble with returning array from included file for config

Tags: php, configuration

I'm trying to do a simple config class to read arrays from config files.
Where you include the file which has return array() contents. Easy enough.

I thought I'd extend it a bit to use dot notation with the first element being the file name. But if you attempt to access data within that same file twice, it attempts to include the file a second time, which doesn't work.

```
public static function get($path=null,$ext='php'){
    if(!$path)return false;

    $path = explode('.',$path);
    $file = $path[0] . '.' . $ext;

    //remove file name.
    unset($path[0]);

    $files = scandir(CONFIG);

    if(in_array($file,$files)){

        $data = include_once(CONFIG.$file);

        foreach($path as $element){

            if(isset($data[$element])){

                $data = $data[$element];

            }
        }

        return $data;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

 }
```

Works great as long as you don't need anything else from that file anywhere ever again. Is there a simple fix here, or am I completely wet?

Comment: If you replace `include_once` with `include`, you can use that file multiple times.

Comment: WTH. I tried that several times to no avail, but now all of the sudden it works...??  Whatever. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should just make class cache variable.. like:

```
public static $configData = array();
```

then on function call, first, check if config file is already loaded in configData. So on function call, check

```
if (!isset(self::$configData[$filename])) {
   ...load not loaded file and get some $configurationFromFile array..
   self::$configData[$filename] = $configurationFromFile
}
```

then after checking if everything is loaded

```
if (isset(self::$configData[$filename][$key]) {
  return self::$configData[$filename][$key];
} else {
  return false
}
```

so you will never try to scan that directory again if you already loaded config file.. its good for performance.. and performance must be high for such things as configuration getting.